# Sum Array push values, before a 0 javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I'm trying to take the value of an input and keep it in an array.
I want to detect when the user text 0, and I want to sum all the values in the array before the 0.

Here is my code:

```
<form id="demo">
    <input type="number" id="lala">
    <button onclick='funsuma(this.form.lala.value)' > NO <button/>
</form> 

<script>
    var global = [];
    var suma = 0;

    function funsuma(valor) {
        global.push(valor);
        for (i = 0; i < global.length; i++) {
            if (global[i] == 0) {
                suma += parseInt(global[i], 10);
                alert("Es 0, tu suma es: " + suma);
                return false;
            } else {
                //alert(global[i]);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<input type='number' id='lala'> <button value='Envia' onclick='funsuma(this.form.lala.value)'> NO <button/>";
                return false;
            }   
        }

        //console.log("global");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: I put the values, an example: 1, 5, 6, 0
when i put 0 it doesn't sum the values before the 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do to

```js
var global = [];

function funsuma(valor) {
  var suma = 0;

  //need to make sure valor is a number
  global.push(+valor);

  if (valor == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < global.length; i++) {
      suma += global[i];
    }
    alert("Es 0, tu suma es: " + suma);
    //based on your logic you need to see whether to reset the array
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="demo">
  <input type="number" id="lala" />
  <button onclick='return funsuma(this.form.lala.value)'>NO</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a form for this, nor do you need to clear the innerHtml and reset it constantly. You can use event listeners and set the value of the input in the js.

```
<input type="number" id="lala" />
<button type="button" id="sum"></button>

(function(document){
    var input = document.getElementById('lala');
    var button = document.getElementById('sum');
    var global = [];

    var buttonClick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        if(!isNaN(input.value)){
            if(input.value === 0){
                var sum = 0;

                for(var i = 0; i < global.length; i++){
                    sum += global[i];
                }

                alert('Sum is ' + sum);
                global.splice(0, global.length);
            } else{
                global.push(input.value);
                input.value = '';
            }
        } else{
            //if they somehow get a non-number input
            input.value = '';
        }
    };

    button.addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
})(document);
```